# Read row values with entities

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a Pie Chart and its name-value pair are being retrieved from the database.

[image]

how to read the row details in order to get the values and store it one property ?

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {

        Ram.DataContext = new List<UsageRAM>() 
          { new UsageRAM() { name = "Available" , value =/*how to get the value here*/ },
            new UsageRAM() { name = "Used" , value =/*how to get the value here*/ }};
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

 public class UsageRAM
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

--Answer which worked for me--

```
        using (DB db = new DB())
        {
            var row = (from c in db.UsageRAMs
                       orderby c.UsageRamID descending
                       select c).First();

            Ram.DataContext = new List<UsageRAM>() 
              { new UsageRAM() { name = "Available" , value = row.Available},
               new UsageRAM() { name = "Used"  , value = row.Used }};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using EF, simply add  a new model to your project and include the requried  table(s) in this model. Then you can use the newly created Entities object to read your db values as follows:

```
var Rows = context.YourTableName.Where(YourCondition).ToArray();
```

You can then iterate over the Rows collection using foreach or something.

If you need to read values from a single row, you may want to use `First` instead of `Where` above. That will return a single object whose properties will map to your db fields and can directly be assigned in the example code you posted in the question.

**EXAMPLE**

Say your model's Entity class is named MyEntities and it contains the table UsageRam, which has two fields Available and Used. Then it will take the following code:

```
using(MyEntities e = new MyEntities)
{
    var Row = e.MyTable.First(x => x.UsageRamID = **[ID]**);

    MessageBox.Show("Available=" + Row.Available.ToString() + ",Used=" + Row.Used.ToString();
}
```

I have just shown values in message box, you can assign them to anything you want.

**Another Example**

```
using(MyEntities e = new MyEntities)
{
    var Rows = e.MyTable.Where(x => x.UsageRamID > 10 &&  x.UsageRamID < 20);

    foreach(var Row in Rows)
        MessageBox.Show("Available=" + Row.Available.ToString() + ",Used=" + Row.Used.ToString();
}
```

**EXAMPLE 3**

The code in your updated post appears fine to me, though I do have some doubts about the db design, but given your table is indexed on RamUsageID column, this should give you correct results without much performance impact. I generally prefer lambada expressions over query, so I'd rather write it like:

```
db.RamUsage.OrderByDescending(x => x.RamUsageID).First()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using EF only.. but I don know how to iterate. could pls show some tiny piece of example..that would help me to proceed further. thanks

Comment: You haven't provided any information about you Model, the table(s) involved, the PK etc. I'm posting a small example above, hope you can continue from there onwards.

Comment: thanks indeed. this is how my table looks like http://s8.postimage.org/tvzhbd61h/namval2.png

Comment: Always consider showing your appreciation using the green check mark on the left if the answer helps you. :)

Comment: sure. I will. one last question , as u hav assigned it to a msgbox, is it possbile to assign it to my list<UsageRAM> ?

Comment: Of course, why not. The only difference is that if you have a List<T>, I assume you are expecting multiple rows in the results. In that case, you should use Where() instead of First() to fetch your results and then use a simple loop to iterate over the results, adding or modifying objects in the list, assigning them values form the current row's properties. I'll post another example.

Comment: I am sorry to disturb u again. but pls check my EDIT. is this the right way to do it? I want only the latest value, hence I have used the First(), or is it ok to use Take(1)

Comment: Thank u soo much sir, it worked like charm.. but pls post your example, it wil be helpful to others too.

Comment: Yes the last one sounds better than my query.. thanks @dotNET